# Vertx-js Event bus not receiving data from sender

Tags: javascript, cluster-computing, publish-subscribe, vert.x

I have used vertx-js event bus example from official github repository under the core examples.

Even though its not sending data from sender to receiver.

**Sender.js**

```
var eb = vertx.eventBus();

// Send a message every second

vertx.setPeriodic(1000, function (v) {

  eb.send("ping-address", "ping!", function (reply, reply_err) {
    if (reply_err == null) {
      console.log("Received reply " + reply.body());
    } else {
      console.log("No reply");
    }
  });

});
```

**Reciever.js**

```
var eb = vertx.eventBus();

eb.consumer("ping-address", function (message) {

  console.log("Received message: " + message.body());
  // Now send back reply
  message.reply("pong!");
});

console.log("Receiver ready!");
```

I Have used the following method to run a program .

**vertx run reciever.js -cluster**
**vertx run sender.js -cluster**

Comment: This looks like a clustering issue. Have a look at http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/#_trouble_shooting_clustering

Comment: are you using hazeclast   ( http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/whatsnew.html ) for clustering ? and   is there cluster.xml is configured ?

Comment: Thanks all its working fine. While running the vertx file used the same IP mentioned in XML file in Vertx Configuration.